# LIBGDX making 5 different buttons on one screen

Tags: java, android, 2d, desktop, libgdx

I have 5 buttons i need to make do different things but they don't and i need to know how to make them do it.

Here is my code;

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen {

CrazyZombies game;
Stage stage;
TextureAtlas atlas;
Skin skin;
SpriteBatch batch;
Button play, option, quit, custom, store, menu;

public MainMenu(CrazyZombies game) {
    this.game = game;
}

public void create () {
    stage = new Stage();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.09f, 0.28f, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();

    batch.begin();
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    if (stage == null)
        stage = new Stage(width, height, true);
    stage.clear();

    stage.setViewport(854, 480, true);
    stage.getCamera().translate(-stage.getGutterWidth(), -stage.getGutterHeight(), 0);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    /**
     * quit Button
     */

    TextButtonStyle styleQuit = new TextButtonStyle();
    styleQuit.up = skin.getDrawable("8layer");
    styleQuit.down = skin.getDrawable("8layer");

    quit = new Button(styleQuit);

    quit.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {

        }
    });

    /**
     * End quit Button
     */

     /**
      * store Button
      */

    TextButtonStyle styleStore = new TextButtonStyle();
    styleStore.up = skin.getDrawable("9layer");
    styleStore.down = skin.getDrawable("9layer");

    store = new Button(styleStore);

    store.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            game.setScreen(new StoreScreen(game));
        }
    });

    /**
     * End store Button
     */

     /**
      * customs Button
      */

    TextButtonStyle styleCustom = new TextButtonStyle();
    styleCustom.up = skin.getDrawable("10layer");
    styleCustom.down = skin.getDrawable("10layer");

    custom = new Button(styleCustom);

    custom.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            game.setScreen(new CustomScreen(game));
        }
    });

    /**
     * End customs Button
     */

     /**
      * Options Button
      */

    TextButtonStyle styleOptions = new TextButtonStyle();
    styleOptions.up = skin.getDrawable("11layer");
    styleOptions.down = skin.getDrawable("11layer");

    option = new Button(styleOptions);

    option.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            game.setScreen(new OptionScreen(game));
        }
    });

    /**
     * End Options Button
     */

     /**
      * Play Button
      */

    TextButtonStyle stylePlay = new TextButtonStyle();
    stylePlay.up = skin.getDrawable("7layer");
    stylePlay.down = skin.getDrawable("7layer");

    play = new Button(stylePlay);

    play.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log(CrazyZombies.LOG, "un-touched");
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        }
    });

    /**
     * End Play Button
     */

    /**
     * start Background
     */

    TextButtonStyle styleMenu = new TextButtonStyle();
    styleMenu.up = skin.getDrawable("background");

    menu = new Button(styleMenu);

    /**
     * End Background
     */

    stage.addActor(menu);
    stage.addActor(play);
    stage.addActor(option);
    stage.addActor(store);
    stage.addActor(custom);
    stage.addActor(quit);

}

@Override
public void show() {
    Audio.playMusic(true);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    atlas = new TextureAtlas("data/mainmenu/mainmenu.pack");
    skin = new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(atlas);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
    atlas.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
    Audio.dispose();
}

public void playButton(Button play) {

}
}
```

So my 5 buttons are set up and there actions and listeners but now they do not do anything and when i single one button out to test it works but the button can be clicked from any where on the screen so i think it is an issue with button areas but i do not know how to set it up.

I have tryed .getheight(), .getWidth etc. but it is still the same. Although in my texture atlas the height and width for all the images is the same as it all makes one image could this be my issue ?

Comment: are the buttons connected to the layout resource?

Comment: What do you mean by the layout resource ?

Comment: wasn't clear if you had set a layout like R.layout.main or something that made buttons appear. an xml layout file resource.

Comment: Oh no i am getting my images from an atlas i havent put them into any sort of table or anything

Comment: @LanternMike : LibGDX doesn't use the same system as Android for UI as it is OS specific, it has it's own UI API. `Button`, event if it has the same name as the `View` in Android, is also a LibGDX class.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's more simple than that. You need to set the bounds of your buttons. Use the `.setBounds(x,y,width,height)` method of the button, they do not have a size yet. The click area should be right after setting the bounds.

Take a look at  [Table layout libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/table-layout/) and use a table.

Answer (score 0):

For your **first problem**, which is that your buttons doesn't do anything, I think it's because the event is propagated to all of your buttons, probably in the order they have been added to the `Stage`. The problem is that your `touchDown()` method returns **true**. It means that the propagation should stop and then the `touchDown()` method of your others actors doesn't get called.
You feel like it does nothing but in fact it does something, it's just that your `touchDown()` method is empty.

For you **second problem**, it's probably because your didn't set the size of your actors.